# Realm update results in database from server

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to sync my data with json api, but when im making request second time(im editing data on a server side), data in ream is still old, are there any way to sync both server and realm db

my shema in realm :

```
  class testObject: Object {

    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var url: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id" 
  }
}
```

Request:

```
func request() {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/products.json")
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {  (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("error != nil")
                print(error)
            } else {

                var jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
                 // Crashes on this line

                do {
                    let realm = try Realm()
                    try! realm.write({ () -> Void in
                        for info in jsonData {
                            let user = Mapper<testObject>().toJSON
                            realm.create(testObject.self, value: info, update: true)

                        }
                    })

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }



            }
        }


        task.resume()


    }
```

in my UITableViewController im calling in viewDidLoad():

```
func reloadMyTable() {

        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            self.datasource = realm.objects(testObject)
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

notificationToken:
[image]

Comment: Have you validated that the server is returning an object with the same `id`?

Comment: for now im trying to delete an item, and want to see updated tableView

Comment: I just saw that you noted a crash at `jsonData`, but that wasn't quite obvious from your question to me. Is that what's your question about? If so, can you elaborate on that and show the stack trace?

Comment: @marius updated question

Comment: @Діма Комар: Can you share the implementation of your `tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)` method?

Comment: @marius just a single line return datasource.count

Comment: When `datasource` is declared as implicit unwrapped optional, you need to make sure that it is always initialized to a value before it is accessed anywhere. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @marius ok, that builds for now :) 
but when i remove object from server its still not removing on realm db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96061/discussion-between---and-marius).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you trigger an asynchronous network request and are loading your `UITableViewController` concurrently. So the new data seems to be not loaded yet, while you're trying to render the results.

To achieve that you can listen to write notifications on the Realm.

```
var notificationToken: NotificationToken?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.datasource = realm.objects(testObject) // is auto-updated

    notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { note, realm in
       self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

deinit {
    if let notificationToken = notificationToken {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        realm.removeNotification(notificationToken)
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing changed in fact,
im getting nil in the numberOfRowsInSection if i dont calling my own  func reloadMyTable()